# The struct is not storing data? Not sure what I am doing wrong

Tags: c

I have not coded in C before and trying to understand what's going on.

So I have a  text file like this:

```
ID = 111222333
Username = Fred03
Email = Fred@GlobecksCorp.comp
Password = X3tyvfy%@#
First name = Fred
Last name = Torick
Department = Finance
Salary = 84000
Employed = True

ID = 111222334
Username = Fred04
Email = Fred4@GlobecksCorp.comp
Password = fr3dD01.2$4
First name = Fred
Last name = Do
Department = Software Developer
Salary = 90000
Employed = True

ID = 111222335
Username = BriDev05
Email = BrianDev@GlobecksCorp.comp
Password = d3vF7BvNgl2
First name = Brian
Last name = Nguyen
Department = Software QA-Tester
Salary = 95000
Employed = True
```

I am trying to read the text file and store it to  the struct. So there are three employees in this text file. I  think my struct should store  them accordingly as index 0,1,2.  I notice that my struct is not storing first  two employees and storing just the third employees three time.

For reference, Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee{
    char* userName; 
    char*  email;
    char* password;
    char* id;
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
    char* salary;
    char* department;
    char*  isEmployed; 
};


int main() {
   char fname [100];
   char lname[100];
   char department[100];
   char password [100];
   char  salary[100];
   char  isEmployed [100];
   char email[100];
   char ID[100]; 
   char username[100]; 

   struct employee employeeList[10];



    char buf[80];
    FILE *file;

    if ((file = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open test.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

   int i = -1;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file)) {

      
      
     // printf( "My i value is: %d\n", i);
        if (buf[strspn(buf, " ")] == '\n')  /* accept blank lines */
            continue;

      if (sscanf(buf, " ID = %s", &ID) == 1){
            //printf("%s\n", &ID);
             i++;
            employeeList[i].id = ID;
          
          }

       if (sscanf(buf, " Username = %s", &username) == 1){
            employeeList[i].userName = username;
        }

       if (sscanf(buf, " Email = %s", &email) == 1){
           //printf("%s\n", &email);
            employeeList[i].email = email;
        }

      if (sscanf(buf, "Password  = %s", &password) == 1){
           // printf("%s\n", &password);
            employeeList[i].password = &password;
      }

      if (sscanf(buf, "First name  = %s", &fname) == 1){
          //  printf("%s\n", &fname);
          employeeList[i].firstName = &fname;
      }

      if (sscanf(buf, "Last name  = %s", &lname) == 1){
           employeeList[i].lastName = &lname;
      }

      if (sscanf(buf, "Department  = %s", &department) == 1){
            employeeList[i].department = department;
      }

      if (sscanf(buf, "Salary  = %s", &salary) == 1){
            //printf("%s\n", &salary);
            employeeList[i].salary = salary;
      }

      if (sscanf(buf, "Employed  = %s", &isEmployed) == 1){
           // printf("%s\n", isEmployed);
      }      
    }
    fclose(file);


  

   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
     printf("%s\n",employeeList[i].id);
   }

  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it seems you are not incrementing your loop counter in the correct place. you should probably increment `i` at the end of your `while` loop right?

Comment: @D3PSI  I tried  that but  it also just store the last value once.

Comment: @B__ that cause segmentation fault

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Making a _minimal_ example takes a bit of work on the questioner's part.

Comment: @Elliott  If you run the code I think it will be really easy for you to see the problem.  I tried to create a minimal reproducible example but I think  for this example  it's quite hard to create.

Comment: `sscanf(buf, "Department  = %s", &department)` fails to read all of the department as the department is not 1 word. This begins a series of mis-read input.

Comment: All members of struct are `char*` and you've to allocate memory to each of them & use `strncpy()` to copy contents.  Also, tokenise the reads check what you got as a `key=value` pair then assign values. Empty lines can be `the` separator between records.

Comment: please do not erase the question once solved, the idea is that others can benefit from reading the Q and A

Comment: `ID` and `Username` are probably [redundant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: If this is for something real, learn about [password hashing](https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-passwords-one-way-road-to-security/).

Answer (score 1):

This code works on my Linux machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee{
    char userName[100];
    char email[100];
    char password[100];
    char id[100];
    char firstName[100];
    char lastName[100];
    char salary[100];
    char department[100];
    char isEmployed[100];
};


int main() {
    char fname [100];
    char lname[100];
    char department[100];
    char password [100];
    char salary[100];
    char isEmployed [100];
    char email[100];
    char ID[100];
    char username[100];

    struct employee employeeList[10];

    char buf[80];
    FILE *file;

    if ((file = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open test.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int i = -1;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file)) {

        if (buf[strspn(buf, " ")] == '\n')  /* accept blank lines */
            continue;

        if (sscanf(buf, " ID = %s", &ID) == 1) {
            i++;
            strcpy(employeeList[i].id, ID);
        }

        if (sscanf(buf, " Username = %s", &username) == 1) {
            strcpy(employeeList[i].userName, username);
        }

        if (sscanf(buf, " Email = %s", &email) == 1) {
            strcpy(employeeList[i].email, email);
        }

        if (sscanf(buf, "Password  = %s", &password) == 1) {
            strcpy(employeeList[i].password, password);
        }

        if (sscanf(buf, "First name  = %s", &fname) == 1) {
            strcpy(employeeList[i].firstName, fname);
        }

        if (sscanf(buf, "Last name  = %s", &lname) == 1) {
            strcpy(employeeList[i].lastName, lname);
        }

        if (sscanf(buf, "Department  = %s", &department) == 1) {
            strcpy(employeeList[i].department, department);
        }

      if (sscanf(buf, "Salary  = %s", &salary) == 1) {
            strcpy(employeeList[i].salary, salary);
      }

      if (sscanf(buf, "Employed  = %s", &isEmployed) == 1) {
           // printf("%s\n", isEmployed);
      }
    }

    fclose(file);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", employeeList[i].id);
        printf("%s\n", employeeList[i].userName);
        printf("%s\n", employeeList[i].email);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I modified the employee struct to contain arrays rather than pointers:

```
struct employee{
    char userName[100];
    char email[100];
    char password[100];
    char id[100];
    char firstName[100];
    char lastName[100];
    char salary[100];
    char department[100];
    char isEmployed[100];
};
```

I also modified the assignment operators with the 'strcpy' function:

```
strcpy(employeeList[i].id, ID);
strcpy(employeeList[i].userName, username);
strcpy(employeeList[i].email, email);
strcpy(employeeList[i].password, password);
strcpy(employeeList[i].firstName, fname);
strcpy(employeeList[i].lastName, lname);
strcpy(employeeList[i].department, department);
strcpy(employeeList[i].salary, salary);
```

I believe the problem with the original code was that the 'employeeList[i].id' pointers were pointing to the local char array variable 'ID'. This means that when 'ID' goes from '111222333' to '111222334' to '111222335', all of the pointers in 'employeeList[i].id' get updated with those values. In other words, the 'employeeList[i].id' pointers are pointing to the memory address of 'ID'.

To avoid this, I used the 'strcpy' function instead of the assign operator '=' to copy the string and not the address of 'ID'. However, 'strcpy' does not work on pointers that have no memory assigned to them. That is why I used arrays instead of pointers for the 'employee' struct. As a side note, you can dynamically allocate memory to those pointers to avoid having to use arrays.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I    I figured it out. We can do temp pointer and malloc some spaces  on that. If I copy it and  and then assign that to the struct and it perfectly works.  I don't wanted to to change to struct  but thank you again for trying and getting a solution